# VBA: How to change the value of another cell via a function?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an Excel VBA newbie.

How to change the value of the specified cell via a user-defined function? What's wrong with this code:

```
Function Test(ByVal ACell As Range) As String
  ACell.Value = "This text is set by a function"
  Test := "Result"
End Function
```

My wish is ... when I type `=Test(E6)` in cell E1, Excel will display the specified text in E6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel VBA will not allow a user-defined function to alter the value of another cell.
The only thing a UDF is allowed to do (with a few minor exceptions) is to return values to the cells it is called from.

Answer (score 8):

YES, of course, it is possible.

[image]

Put this code in Module1 of VBA editor:

```
Function UDF_RectangleArea(A As Integer, B As Integer)
    Evaluate "FireYourMacro(" & Application.Caller.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False) & "," & A & "," & B & ")"
    UDF_RectangleArea = "Hello world"
End Function

Private Sub FireYourMacro(ResultCell As Range, A As Integer, B As Integer)
    ResultCell = A * B
End Sub
```

The result of this example UDF is returned in another, adjacent cell. The user defined function `UDF_RectangleArea` calculates the rectangle area based on its two parameters `A` and `B` and returns result in a cell to the right. You can easily modify this example function.

The limitation Microsoft imposed on function is bypassed by the use of VBA [Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/foxpro/aa977640(v=vs.71)) function. Evaluate simply fires VBA macro from within UDF. The reference to the cell is passed by `Application.Caller`. Have fun!

UDF limitation documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: Cool! I suppose `Rectangle = "Hello world"` should read `UDF_RectangleArea = "Hello world"`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @vpprof I do not get your comment. I cannot see `Rectangle = "Hello world"` you are referencing.

Comment: It's in your `Function UDF_RectangleArea`, just before the end of the function...

Comment: @vpprof yes, you are right. I have corrected it in answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A VBA UDF can be used as an array function to return results to multiple adjacent cells.
Enter the formula into E1 and E2 and press Ctrl-Shift-Enter to create a multi-cell array formula. Your UDF would look something like this:

```
Public Function TestArray(rng As Range)
    Dim Ansa(1 To 2, 1 To 1) As Variant
    Ansa(1, 1) = "First answer"
    Ansa(2, 1) = "Second answer"
    TestArray = Ansa
End Function
```

Comment: Aha, that's a nice solution too. Thanks @Charles, I appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just typing you formula in E6 then ? That's the Excel logic: put your formula where you want the result to appear.

Comment: I'm creating a long function that will return two result. Since it is a long function and the results can be calculated just once, calling it twice from different cells should decrease the speed of the sheet when displaying the results. However, if the answer of my question is impossible, I think, I will add one more parameter that specifies which one of the result is needed.