# Error getting return value from user defined function

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

My user defined function always returns 'A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type' (I am passing cell ranges to the function). I've searched lots of threads and am quite sure my code should work:

```
Function SortAndEvaluate(ByRef Probs() As Variant, ByRef ResidualProbs() As Variant, ByRef Costs() As Variant)
    Dim Temp As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NoExcanges As Integer


    'Exchange values in probs in descending order

    Do
        NoExchanges = True
        ' Loop through each element
        For i = 0 To UBound(Probs) - 1

            'If element is greater than the last exchange, else do nothing

            If Probs(i) > Probs(i + 1) Then
                NoExchanges = False
                ' Exchange probability values
                Temp = Probs(i)
                Probs(i) = Probs(i + 1)
                Probs(i + 1) = Temp
                ' Exchange residual probability values
                Temp = ResidualProbs(i)
                ResidualProbs(i) = ResidualProbs(i + 1)
                ResidualProbs(i + 1) = Temp
                ' Exchange cost values
                Temp = Costs(i)
                Costs(i) = Costs(i + 1)
                Costs(i + 1) = Temp
            End If
        Next i
    Loop While Not (NoExchanges)

    Temp = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(Probs)
        If i = 1 Then
            Temp = Temp + Probs(i) * Costs(i)
        Else
            Temp = Temp + Probs(i) * ResidualProbs(i - 1) * Costs(i)
        End If
    Next i

    SortAndEvaluate = Temp
End Function
```

Can anyone give me any feedback please?

Comment: If you could also provide some sample data to pass to your function, this would make understadning/debugging easier! Few first remarks:
1. Use Option Explicit
2. You dim NoExcanges` as integer, but access `NoExcHanges` as boolean
3. What data type should your function return?

Comment: +1 for `Option Explicit`!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Sample Data for variables Probs = {0,13 ; 0,016 ; 0,004}, ResidualProbs = {0,02 ; 0,004; 0,00} , Costs = {1;2;3;4}. The values I gave are actually in separate columns and I pass the ranges to the function. The return data type is a floating point number. Could you elaborate on the Option = Explicit part? Where would this go?

Comment: write the text `Option Explicit` on the [very first line of the Class Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: From MSDN, "When Option Explicit appears in a file, you must explicitly declare all variables using the Dim or ReDim statements. If you attempt to use an undeclared variable name, an error occurs at compile time. Use Option Explicit to avoid incorrectly typing the name of an existing variable or to avoid confusion in code where the scope of the variable is not clear. If you do not use the Option Explicit statement, all undeclared variables are of Object type."

Comment: I have made all the changes you suggested, but strangely it does not seem to have solved the problem. FYI, the function is called like this: =SortAndEvaluate(G33:G35;H33:H35;I33:I35)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
Option Explicit

Function SortAndEvaluate(ByRef Probs As Range, ByRef ResidualProbs As Range, ByRef Costs As Range)

    Dim NumberOfProbs As Long
    Dim NumberOfProbsRows As Long
    Dim NumberOfProbsColumns As Long
    Dim RangeAddressProbs As String

    ' Dim for ResidualProbs and Costs
    ' ...

    NumberOfProbs = Probs.Cells.Count
    NumberOfProbsRows = Probs.Rows.Count
    NumberOfProbsColumns = Probs.Columns.Count
    RangeAddressProbs = Probs.Address

    ' also for ResidualProbs and Costs
    ' ...

    ' Might want some validation, e.g.
    If NumberOfProbsColumns <> 1 Then Exit Function
    If NumberOfResidualProbsColumns <> 1 Then Exit Function

    ' Get Values from range as an array
    Dim ValuesProbs As Variant
    Dim ValuesResidualProbs As Variant
    Dim ValuesCosts As Variant

    ValuesProbs = Probs
    ValuesResidualProbs = ResidualProbs
    ValuesCosts = Costs

    ' Do your logic stuff using the Values... arrays
    ' ...

    ' This example return value shows how to reference the Values... arrays (note you need to index the column too)
    SortAndEvaluate = ValuesProbs(NumberOfProbsRows, 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. I now finally get an output other than the error message I got in the beginning, but the result is always zero. To test why the result is always zero I omitted all the logic part and just tried to get my function to output the first value in the Probs column (see attached code). The result is still always zero. 'ValuesProbs = Probs' Is this really how I pass the values from the ranges to a new array?

Comment: Edit: problem solved, had a little typo in there! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Option Explicit and you also have a typographical error in your code for where you `Dim NoExcanges As Integer`.

When you later write `NoExchanges = True` this implicitly `Dim`s a new type of Boolean with the reference `NoExchanges` — `NoExcanges` is never used.

You also might want to explicitly declre the return type of your function:

`Function SortAndEvaluate(ByRef Probs() As Variant, ByRef ResidualProbs() As Variant, ByRef Costs() As Variant) As Double`

Comment: I have corrected the NoExchanges error, specified the return data type and declared Option Explicit - no success so far.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input data ranges and the exact formula you are using to call the Function?

Comment: I call the function as follows (in any empty field) =SortAndEvaluate(G33:G35;H33:H35;I33:I35). I provided sample data in one of my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Excel VBA will not allow a user-defined function to alter the value of another cell. The only thing a UDF is allowed to do (with a few minor exceptions) is to return values to the cells it is called from.

The line `Probs(i) = Probs(i + 1)` is simply not allowed inside a Function.

See similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844792/vba-how-to-change-the-value-of-another-cell-via-a-function)

You can do this with a Sub but you would have to pass the cells to sort in another way (possibly using `Selection`).

Comment: But I am not actually trying to alter the cell values that I am referencing in the function arguments - I merely want to sort them (only inside the function - not the actual Excel table), so I can return a result to the target cell. Can't I make a "copy" of the values, rearrange them and then return the result to an unused cell? I thought that's what I was doing - do correct me if I'm wrong. Although I am not new to programming I am a complete beginner when it comes to VBA.

Comment: That is much easier to do. Your issue arises because `Probs(i) = Probs(i + 1)` tries to change the value of the cell you passed as a reference.