# #value! error while using Range object in VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write my first vba macro for excel 2010. It needs to do  some long calculations for 200,000 rows and needs to populate 2 adjacent cells on the active row. The following VBA function is a crude first attempt to accomplish the above. Problem is while executing the macro, I get #value! error. If I remove "cells" and .Value lines, it works fine and populates the activecell with appropriate value. What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate the help very much.

```
Public Function someCalculation() As Integer

    Dim r As Range
    Dim nrow, ncol As Integer

    nrow = ActiveCell.Row
    ncol = ActiveCell.Column

    r = Cells(nrow, ncol + 1)
    r.Value = nrow * 100 + ncol

    someCalculation = nrow * 1000 + ncol

End Function
```

Comment: You cannot set the value of any cell in the workbook other than the cell in which the *User Defined Function* (aka **UDF**) resides. Your requirement that it *'needs to populate 2 adjacent cells on the active row'* cannot be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Cells" is an object, you must use 'Set' with any object to assign it.

But it's not possible to modify another cells than the one with function.

Edit : remove wrong code

```
    Set r = Cells(nrow, ncol + 1)
```

Comment: No luck, same error after the change. FYI, I am using the macro as "=someCalculation()" in the active worksheet

Comment: Oops, I'm using run from VBA... It's not allowed to modify a another cells from a function. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844792/vba-how-to-change-the-value-of-another-cell-via-a-function)

Comment: thanks a bunch for the pointer using the SO link. The approach provided there provided me the way to accomplish what I wanted to do. Using the array function. At least it will get me over the hump right now.