# excel vba - insert value into cell

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to put data into a cell via a VBA script.

Why can't I call it directly in the worksheet with function()?

If I call the function direct in the editor it works.

## Example code:

```
 Function sbWriteIntoCellData()
       Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Hello World";
 End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: How to change the value of another cell via a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844792/vba-how-to-change-the-value-of-another-cell-via-a-function)

Comment: That post does not answer my question, why I can't call the function direktly in the worksheet cell. I have a larger programm in which modul the function is called by a button event and it works. I'am now confused why this simple example doesn't works ...

Comment: Because you *cannot alter the value of another cell in a user defined function* when you call that function from the sheet.  A UDF is supposed to return a value not alter content.

Comment: If I use a Sub, would that be possible? In my programm I the following code worked to insert a value into a cell:   In my programm I the following code worked to insert a value into a cell:   Dim cCnt As Integer
cCnt = 2
  Do
  If IsEmpty(Workbooks("mySQL_interface.xlsm").Worksheets("id_list").Cells(cCnt + 1, 2)) Then
       Workbooks("mySQL_interface.xlsm").Worksheets("id_list").Cells(cCnt + 1, 2) = newId
      Exit Do
      End If
      cCnt = cCnt + 1
    Loop

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a Modul for the function, otherwise you wont be able to call it.

The function has to be declared as public and it NEEDS a return value. Your Function had to look like that in order to work:

```
Public Function sbWriteIntoCellData() As String
sbWriteIntoCellData = "Hello World"
End Function
```

Now it writes "Hello World" into the Cell that its called from. You call this function with =sbWriteIntoCellData.

Comment: Thank's for your reply. Now I want to put a stringvalue to more than one cells. If I adress a cell with: workbooks(1).worksheet("table1").cells(5,99) = anyString it does not work.

Comment: There are a few errors in your code. You CANT do that with a funtion that you call from the sheet. Instead use a Macro, you can use a button or just press f5 in the macro. The Syntax has to be : `Worksheets instead of Worksheet` and you need to address the content of the Cell with `.Value` so it should look like this. `Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Test"` . The Main difference between a function and a sub is, that a function can return values. You dont need that for your purposes.