# write a specific split function with vba

Tags: vba

I am writing a vba code to split some texts base on a delimiter and then write each word in a cell.
but the code is only able to split numbers and not the text. I don't know what is wrong. please help me

```
Function mysplit(strText As String, delimiter As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nchoose As Integer
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim delimiterposition As Integer
    Dim r1 As Range
    
    Set r1 = Application.Caller
    delimiterposition = InStr(strText, delimiter)
    i = 1
    nchoose = 1
    Do Until delimiterposition = 0
        str1 = Left(strText, delimiterposition - 1)
        strText = Right(strText, Len(strText) - delimiterposition)
        delimiterposition = InStr(strText, delimiter)
        Evaluate "other_cell_writer(" & r1.Offset(0, i).Address(False, False) & "," & str1 & "," & nchoose & ")"
        i = i + 1
        nchoose = -1 * nchoose
        Loop
        Evaluate "other_cell_writer(" & r1.Offset(0, i).Address(False, False) & "," & strText & "," & nchoose & ")"
        mysplit = "ok"
End Function

Sub other_cell_writer(ResultCell As Range, str1 As String, nchoose As Integer)
    ResultCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = str1
    ResultCell.Value = str1
    If nchoose = 1 Then
        ResultCell.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        ResultCell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        ResultCell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    ElseIf nchoose = -1 Then
        ResultCell.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        ResultCell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        ResultCell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use the built-in VBA `Split()` function?

Comment: my problem is with writing the texts in different cells

Comment: plus I want to change cell formats

Comment: You can just write the split values to a range like this `Range("A2:E2") = Split("1,2,3,4,5", ",")` and then format them any way you want.

Comment: I want to run it as an excel function which it gives me " #value! ". I read somewhere to use a sub in my function to solve this problem

Comment: You mean the value you are trying to split is an error? You can check that condition with `IsError()` and then not even try to split it.

Comment: my problem here come with the Evalute function which runs only when str1 is a number so does not write the string values for me

Comment: excel will not change other cells values by functions when we are calling the function in another cell. so it prints the results to that cell and unable to change other cells or print results there

Comment: that is why I had to call "other_cell_writer" within my function

Comment: I find the idea here suggested by Przemyslaw Remin:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844792/vba-how-to-change-the-value-of-another-cell-via-a-function

Comment: Would help to show an example of the data you’re working with

Comment: for example I want to split these: "Ali,22,Raha,23" and write eachone in a different cell like "Ali","22","Raha","23" but my code only writes "","22","","23"

Answer (score 2):

You're not quoting the arguments correctly in the call to `Evaluate`

This worked for me:

```vb
Function mysplit(strText As String, delimiter As String)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Application.ThisCell
    c.Parent.Evaluate "other_cell_writer(" & c.Address() & ",""" & strText & """,""" & delimiter & """)"
    mysplit = "ok"
End Function

Function other_cell_writer(FormulaCell As Range, str1 As String, delim As String)
    
    Dim arr, v, i, n
    
    arr = Split(str1, delim)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        With FormulaCell.Offset(0, n + 1)
            .Value = arr(i)
            .Interior.Color = IIf(i Mod 2 = 0, vbRed, vbYellow)
        End With
        n = n + 1
    Next i
    
End Function
```

Note you really want the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method and not the default (implicit) `Application.Evaluate`, which will use the active sheet as the context for evaluating the call.

If `strText` might contain double-quotes you will need to escape those before concatenating it into the call to `Evaluate`.