# Why the VBA UDF "Range.Formula =" don't work?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I want to copy the formula from one cell/cells to another cell/cells by `Range.Formula =` .
But it not work as expected.

If I run the VBA step by step, the function will ended at `Range.Formula =`  without error.

```
Function test1(sOURCE As Range, tARGET As Range)
    tARGET.Formula = sOURCE.Formula
    test1 = tARGET.Formula
End Function
```

[image: Excel cells value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change another cell's formula with a UDF. According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1) this cannot be done, but Ryan Wells has actually found a nice workaround. See: [How to change another cell with a VBA function UDF](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/how-to-change-another-cell-with-a-vba-function-udf/). Compare also: [VBA: How to change the value of another cell via a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844792/vba-how-to-change-the-value-of-another-cell-via-a-function)

We need to use `Evaluate` on a "helper" sub. I have slightly adjusted the first example provided by Wells to suit your needs:

```
Function copyFormula(copyFrom As Range, copyTo As Range)

copyFrom.Parent.Evaluate "copyOver(" & copyFrom.Address() _
                        & "," & copyTo.Address() & ")"
                        
copyFormula = "Formula " & copyFrom.Address() & " -> " & copyTo.Address()

End Function

Private Sub copyOver(copyFrom As Range, copyTo As Range)

copyTo.Formula = copyFrom.Formula
    
End Sub
```

This works, but please bear in mind that (intriguingly) the formula will not automatically calculate after insertion, even with calculation set to automatic. Implementation:

[image]
Result:

[image]

One way to overcome this problem is to include a `Worksheet_Change` sub for the worksheet where you are using the formula. E.g. simply:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Calculate

End Sub
```

But any subsequent action in the sheet seems to trigger the calculation. Also, please be aware that you won't be able to overwrite the target cell while you have a `copyFormula` in use with this cell. Since it will just keep overwriting it immediately with the formula (with `0` as output, if the above trick isn't applied). This might be confusing to your users.

Comment: can you set values of ranges outside of the current cell the UDF is assigned to?

Answer (score 0):

This is a restriction by design.

Because a UDF cannot change any other cells/formulas. A UDF can only return a **value** to the cell the UDF was used in. Therefore `tARGET.Formula = sOURCE.Formula` is not possible.

Also `test1 = tARGET.Formula` will return the formula of `tARGET` as text. It will not replace the formula used in the cell nor will it evaluate the formula.