# Font.Italic property not working in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I'm trying to set a cell's font to being Italic, and all VBA references I've seen have told me to do it
`cell.Font.Italic = True` as so:

```
Function Test(testcell As Range)
    testcell.Font.Italic = True
    Test = testcell.Font.Italic
End Function
```

But unless the passed-in cell is already Italic the function always returns FALSE with no change to the cell in question.

I've tried using the FontStyle property and even hard coding the cell value, but the cell refuses to change.

```
Function Test(testcell As Range)
    Range("J95").Font.FontStyle = "Italic"
    Test = testcell.Font.Italic
End Function
```

The only way to get the function to return TRUE is to manually set the cell to Italic from the Ribbon, but obviously, that's not what I want.

Comment: For my test cell, the Font is Calbri -size 11, with "General" formatting.  The exact text of the cell is "May be off by 2 hours" (referring to how this receipt was given to me in a different time zone, but that's not important, the test cell itself is just a random cell).

Comment: You cannot change directly another cell with a UDF. For this need a workaround e.g. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55223874) or (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37344343)

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. `UDF`s called indirectly with the `Evaluate` method can do much more than regular `UDF`s, but they also don't have the full capabilities of macros. Among other things, they can't set attributes for `Italic` or `Bold` fonts.
In this case, use another workaround to run the macro. This can be done, for example, by using the `Calculate` event.
In the standard module, you need to put the code:

```
Public italcell As Range
Function CTest(testcell As Range)
    Set italcell = testcell
    CTest = True
End Function
```

And in the worksheet module, the `Calculate` event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   If Not italcell Is Nothing Then _
      italcell.Font.Italic = True
End Sub
```